# Wicket Error path: 'label1' does not exist for page: BarPage

Tags: wicket

I would like to assert some label `label1` in some application. I write the following junit testcase:

```
wicketTester.assertLabel("label1", "Hello!");
```

The page, where the label is added looks like this:

FooPage.java

```
public class FooPage extends WebPage {

    public FooPage() {
        add(new Label("label1", "Hello!"));
    }
}
```

and the corresponed html page looks like this:
FooPage.html

```
<body>
..
...

<div wicket:id="label1"></div>
..
<body>
```

The label `label1` - which i would like to assert- is displayed, when someone clicks on the link

```
<a wicket:id="fooId" href="FooPage">Foo</a>
```

in the following page:

```
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org/">
<body>
    <wicket:panel>

            <div class="xxx">
                <a wicket:id="fooId"
                    href="FooPage">Foo</a>
            </div>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the junit Test, I get the following error:

```
path: 'label1' does not exist for page: BarPage
```

My Question is: How to get the right path for the label `label1`?

Comment: And wicketTester has loaded which page? I guess you are on BarPage, and the Label is on FooPage. Hence the error.

Comment: WicketTester load BarPage and the Label is in FooPar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you clicked link 'fooId' in your test (with wicketTester.clickLink) ?

Comment: hmm no. What effect does it have?

Comment: You said that label is displayed only when user clicks on link 'fooId' right? I don't know the datails of your code but I guess you should click the link to render the label.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out your component path like this

Modify **WicketApplication** class

In Wicket 7

```
getDebugSettings().setComponentPathAttributeName("component_path");
```

In Wicket 6 or older

```
getDebugSettings().setOutputComponentPath(true);
```

**Usage example:**

```
@Override
public RuntimeConfigurationType getConfigurationType() {
    if (Boolean.valueOf(getProperty("development.mode"))) {
        //show component path in html tag
        getDebugSettings().setComponentPathAttributeName("component_path");
        return RuntimeConfigurationType.DEVELOPMENT;
    }       
    return RuntimeConfigurationType.DEPLOYMENT;
}
```

From the web browser if you inspect your component, you will find somthing similar to this:

```
<input type="text" value="" component_path="pageContent_form_username" name="username" id="username3" >
```

Please don't forget to change all the underscores with (:) colons like this:

pageContent_form_username -> pageContent:form:username